# how to get data from database to modal form?

Tags: python, html, flask, sqlalchemy

I am using Flask, Jinja2, Python and SQLAchemy.

I want to retrieve data from my database and display it on my modal.

This is my html code:

```html
     {% extends "layout.html" %}
        {% block title %}
            Admin
        {% endblock %}   
        {% block body %}
          <h1> Admin</h1>
          <div class="form-group">
        <table border=1>
          <tr>
            <th>usa_order_id</th>
            <th>user_id</th>
            <th>product_name</th>
            <th>cpu</th>
     
          </tr>
          {% for usa_order in usa_orders %}
          <tr>
            <th>{{usa_order.usa_order_id}}</th>
            <th>{{usa_order.user_id}}</th>
            <th>{{usa_order.product_name}}</th>
            <th>{{usa_order.cpu}}</th>
            
            <th>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
                Open modal
              </button>    
              <!-- The Modal -->
              <div class="modal" id="myModal">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                  <div class="modal-content">
        
                    <!-- Modal Header -->
                    <div class="modal-header">
        
                      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" >&times;</button>
                    </div>
        
                    <!-- Modal body -->
                    <div class="modal-body">
                      <div class="form-group">
                          <input class="form-control" name ="usa_order_id" value={{usa_order.usa_order_id}}>
                          <input class="form-control" name ="user_id" value={{usa_order.user_id}}>
                          <input class="form-control" name ="cpu" value={{usa_order.cpu}}>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Modal footer -->
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
        
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </th>
          </tr>
        {% endfor %}
        </table>    
          </div>     
            {% endblock %}
```

When I click to open modal, I want it to display the data from my database. I tried some other quick solutions but none of them seem to applicable in Python.

Question is: How can I retrieve data from my db table and display it on the modal - which generated in a `for loop`?

here is my python, just show all the db

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

from  model import *
app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI']='mysql://root:xxx@localhost:3306/xxx'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_COMMIT_ON_TEARDOWN']=True
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


@app.route("/admin")
def index():
    usa_order = usa_order.query.all()
    return render_template("admin.html",usa_order = usa_order)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't provide snippets belong to your routes.py, I will have to assume that you are passing the `usa_orders` data to template without a mistake.

If you want to generate a modal for each `usa_order` in `usa_orders` then you would need to create unique modals for each order. Otherwise, you will end up displaying the same modal for many different users/orders. To achieve this, you simply need to provide a unique id for modal, by editing following line:

```html
              <!-- The Modal -->
              <div class="modal" id="myModal">
```

To something like:

```html
              <!-- The Modal -->
              <div class="modal" id={{usa_order.usa_order_id}}>
```

Or any other unique non-repeating value - preferably from your db.

Let me know if this helps, and if it doesn't work for you: please provide more information on what kind of error(s) you are getting.

Comment: hi thank for reply, it is possible to get the value that show in table html ? if i follow you solution, let say i have more than 100 data then i need to add each of them?? sorry i am new in html

Comment: Thanks for updating with the routes.py. 
I don't see how it shouldn't work. If your db model has has the fields queried then you should be able to loop through all of it. Since your modal is in the `{% for usa_order in usa_orders %}` loop, it should load all the fields as long as you are in the loop. So you give it a try and let me know if it works or not